# Can we approximate the number of possible witnesses for an NP language?

Tags: time-complexity, np

Assuming $L \in NP$, meaning that L could be verified by some $V(x,y)$, such that there exists a polynomial $P(X)$ such that $|y| \leq P(|x|)$ for every $x \in L$.

I was wondering - can I assume something about the possible witness space?
My intuition says that this number is bounded by $O(2^{P(|X|)})$ (all possible subsets of a certain problem, all possible strings by the length at most $P(X)$ etc...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of counting problems associated to languages in NP is called [#P](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Symbols#sharpp). More formally, $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is in $\#P$ if there exists a nondeterministic polynomial time Turing machine $M$ such that for all $x\in\Sigma^*$, $f(x)$ is the number of accepting paths of $M$ on input $x$. This is equivalent to requiring the existence of a deterministic verifier $M(x,y)$ such that $f_M(x)=\big|\big\{y: M(x,y) \text{ accepts}\big\}\big|$.

You ask, given a language in $NP$ with it's verifier $M(x,y)$, can we approximate $f_M$? If the witnesses are of length $p(|x|)$ then obviously $0\le f_M(x)\le 2^{p(|x|)}$, but without knowing more about $M$ then we can't really say anything else about $f_M$. Note that computing $f_M$ is harder than asking whether a witness exists (obviously if you could count then you could determine existence). In fact, counting is considered much harder, as demonstrated by [Toda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda%27s_theorem) (given an oracle for counting, one could decide the entire polynomial hierarchy in polynomial time).

So how hard is approximating such functions, or (allow me to focus on a specific $\#P$ complete language) how hard is it to approximate $\#SAT(\varphi)$, the number of satisfying assignments of a given CNF. In these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f05/lecture9.pdf) by Jonathan Katz, a constant factor approximation is considered, i.e. an algorithm producing a number inside the range $\left[2^{-k}\#SAT(\varphi),2^k\#SAT(\varphi)\right]$ for some fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$. They show that with high probability, given an oracle for regular SAT, one can produce such an approximation in polynomial time (the algorithm can also be strengthen to yield an $1\pm p^{-1}(|\varphi|)$ approximation). So while exact counting is considered much harder than $NP$, an $NP$ oracle is enough to approximate $\#SAT$ with high probability.